# Как выложить веб приложение в интернет?

Tags: хостинг, lamp, devops

Если говорить о сайтах, то все понятно: домен + хостинг.
Веб приложения в компаниях разворачиваются на своих стендах.

А если у меня есть желание и возможность сделать свое небольшое веб приложение, где мне развернуть сервер, где хранить бд? Стандартные хостинги не кажутся надёжным решением. Стек гипотетически mean или lamp, нагрузка максимум 1000 человек в день.